# How to "clean" graphics of embeded exploits?

Tags: linux, exploit, image

I am not totally sure about the terminology but I hear quite a bit about images in websites that somehow take advantage of bugs in software that can be used to compromise a system.
Its not clear to me if these are in the metadata or embedded some other way.
My question is, how can be sure a graphic is not composed? and/or how to "clean" a graphic? If it is in the metadata then I assume something like Metadata Anonymisation Toolkit (MAT) might do the trick? or some more laborious thing like taking a screen shot of the graphic? (but that would be a PITA if I had a batch of images).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not in the metadata. Code is inserted into the image that gets processed by the image viewer.

That means that the easiest option is to corrupt the code. There are many ways to do this:

- compress the image (code is likely not able to survive)
- convert the image into another format (which is a little like "taking a screenshot", but more scalable)
- compose extra data over the image (like a watermark)

Or you can:

- scan the image for malicious code

Compressing becomes the easiest option as it tends to cover the entire file and results in a smaller file, which is a win for resource management.

Comment: Wow, great explanation. And happy to hear that converting is a reasonable option!

Comment: Ironically, some conversion tools might be less robust than the actual viewer.

Answer (score 4):

From a comment on the other answer:

> Wow, great explanation. And happy to hear that converting is a reasonable option!

Unfortunately, the other current answer is incorrect, and the suggestions there, such as using conversion, do not improve security when presented with a malicious image file with an embedded exploit, and can even make things worse.

### Issues with conversion

There is no way to *guarantee* the file is clean. While others have suggested converting from one format to another, this is likely not a safe solution due to the fact that they all use the same libraries, with few exceptions. If there is an exploit embedded in a PNG images, chances are it will be targeting libpng. If it is in a TIFF image, it will be targeting libtiff. These libraries will be used whether you're using an image viewer or a image converter. This means that a vulnerability that affects an image viewer will, with high likelihood, equally affect an image converter.

### Issues with compression

Image compression often does not touch certain parts of the file. If you are doing lossless compression "over" the image, such as compressing it with an archiver, that will preserve any exploit. If you compress it with dedicated tools like optipng or pngcrush, certain parts of the image will be compressed, while other parts will not be. This means that there is no guarantee that you will destroy the malicious components.

### Issues with antivirus

Scanning the image for malicious code only works for exploits with known signatures. Unlike executable files, an IPS/AV cannot run heuristic detection on such files, as each method of exploitation behaves differently.

### Sandboxed conversion

One potential but partial solution would be to use a highly sandboxed conversion utility, such as graphicsmagick in a tight SECCOMP sandbox. Use it to convert to something like PPM or BMP, which are extremely simple and preserve nothing more than the raw, uncompressed image data. This can later be converted back to whatever format you wish. This is not a perfect solution because, in theory, the conversion utility could be compromised to attempt to generate a malicious output file. This would require chaining exploits and is not likely a realistic issue if the output format is simple enough, so this should be good enough. This is sometimes called [normalization](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/security/rule-of-2.md#normalization).

Comment: Six months after your answer, but what about the techniques of 1) adding a tiny bit of random noise, and 2) resizing the image. Would these help?

Comment: @Yogesch Neither of those would help. I'm not sure what adding random noise would entail, but any edit to the image (e.g. a transform like resizing) requires you run it through the same decoder as when you view the image. Adding noise or resizing happens only after you have run it through the vulnerable decoder, not before.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Adding random noise means exactly that. Let me give an example: have an image file to test, and do `convert image.jpg +noise gaussian image.new.jpg`. You'll see the same image but a bit grainy. Now what one could actually do is use `uniform` instead of `gaussian`. You can check here for a short discussion on the noise types http://im.snibgo.com/noise.htm But you're right that it still involves running it through the decoder. Maybe it'd only protect against xss exploits - when the whole image gets slightly modified.

Comment: @Yogesch You could prevent XSS (in some forms) just by reencoding it to PNG. No need to blur it.